# Speed improvement for DataFrame of dict?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict of symbol: DataFrame. Each DataFrame is a time series with an arbitrary number of columns. I want to transform this data structure into a unique time series DataFrame (indexed by date) where each column contains the values of a symbol as a dict.

The following code does what I want, but is slow when it is performed on a dict with hundreds of symbols and DataFrames of 10k rows / 10 columns. I'm looking for ways to improve its speed.

```
import pandas as pd


dates = pd.bdate_range('2010-01-01', '2049-12-31')[:100]

data = {
    'A': pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': range(100), 'col2': range(200, 300)}, index=dates),
    'B': pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': range(100), 'col2': range(300, 400)}, index=dates),
    'C': pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': range(100), 'col2': range(400, 500)}, index=dates)
}

def convert(data, name):
    data = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(data={symbol: [dict(zip(df.columns, v)) for v in df.values]},
                     index=df.index)
        for symbol, df in data.items()
        ], axis=1, join='outer')
    data['type'] = name
    data.index.name = 'date'
    return data

result = convert(data, name='system')
result.head()

                                   A                           B                            C     type
date                
2010-05-18  {'col1': 97, 'col2': 297}   {'col1': 97, 'col2': 397}   {'col1': 97, 'col2': 497}   system
2010-05-19  {'col1': 98, 'col2': 298}   {'col1': 98, 'col2': 398}   {'col1': 98, 'col2': 498}   system
2010-05-20  {'col1': 99, 'col2': 299}   {'col1': 99, 'col2': 399}   {'col1': 99, 'col2': 499}   system
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use Python 3.6

Comment: This is not an advisable structure for pandas  > Each DataFrame is a time series with an "arbitrary number of columns."